# Why does umount --force or --lazy with an SMB share wait for something?

Tags: mount, cifs

What I do:

- mount and SMB share,
- power off the server,
- run `umount -f /mnt/share` or `umount -l /mnt/share`.

And the command hangs for more than a minute. The last call in the backtrace is `umount2`.

My intention is to dismount it and forget about it. I don't need a "gentle disconnect".

I searched a lot but couldn't find and answer why it hangs and what I can do with `umount` to dismount it instantly.

I found this in kernel log:

```
CIFS VFS: Server 10.254.254.2 has not responded in 120 seconds. Reconnecting...
```

...and this in the sources:

```
static bool
server_unresponsive(struct TCP_Server_Info *server)
{
    /*
     * We need to wait 3 echo intervals to make sure we handle such
     * situations right:
```

It seems settings `echo_interval=1` when mounting helps...

But why does it work this way? What's the rationale of not allowing me to close the connection and clean up all the associated resources?

Versions:

```
root@ubuntu:~# mount --version 
mount from util-linux 2.27.1 (libmount 2.27.0: selinux, assert, debug)
root@ubuntu:~# lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: full command? strace it? mount --version? [util-linux jumps through some hoops to try avoid this](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/75c7684724ea203f85bdb60fb0cf28a653ffe85a/libmount/src/context_umount.c#L266-L268) but might not necessarily work

Comment: @frostschutz I updated the question accordingly. I'll run it with `strace` later.

Comment: It may `sync` before trying to `umount`? How long does the `sync` command by itself take?